# Command Button Never Being Hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have a breakpoint on my `e.CommandName` line, but this line is never being hit.  I also tried to add in a catch block that would write to the browswer but I just get an error of "The page can not be displayed" the typical Chrome error thrown when something goes wrong, nothing related to my project.  Below is my code, what is preventing my `e.CommandName` line from being hit?

**C# Page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack) { LoadGrid(); }
}

protected void LoadGrid()
{   
    this.datagrid12.Visible = false;
    this.datagrid12.Visible = true;
    _dataSet = SQLQueryToPullInData
    this.datagrid12.DataSource = _dataSet;
    this.datagrid12.DataBind();
}
```

**Global.Asax**

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
  Server.ClearError();
if (CurrentException != null)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("ErrorLog.txt")))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(CurrentException.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="datagrid12" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnItemCommand="datagrid12_ItemCommand" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="40" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ForeColor="White" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Edit" Text='<%# Eval("uID") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("uID") %>'>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="uID" HeaderText="uID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

**Error written to file from Global.Asax**

> 

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.pages_usersreport_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\cfdef70b\4f768444\App_Web_0tprbakj.1.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Other Code I have tried**

```
protected void datagrid12_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            LinkButton btn = ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnEdit"));
            string uid = btn.CommandArgument;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
    }
```

**EDIT**
I updated my html to add this

```
OnClick="LinkButton_Click"
```

And added the command event to show this:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string commandArgument = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
  string commandName = (sender as LinkButton).CommandName;
  if (commandName == "Edit")
  {
     Response.Redirect("../page2.aspx", false);
  }
}
```

But a breakpoint on `string commandName` is not hit in this instance either.

If I look at the console output for when my page fails to load this is what I see, nothing descriptive to me, but may mean something to another.

> POST http://localhost:1234/page2.aspx net::ERR_Connection_Reset

**EDIT About TimeOut**
I have my query set to not timeout (or so I think) and I have my `MaxHttpCollectionKeys` also set to a very high number as to not time-out.  The query runs fine, and displays results as it should.  The issue lies when I press the linkbutton from the grid that displays.

```
SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000"/>
```

**TO FIX**
To remedy this I had to add the below 2 lines to my web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Instead of setting the OnItemCommand on the grid, have you tried the OnCommand or OnClick event handlers on the LinkButton itself?

Comment: What's going on in page init/load? I'd be concerned about getting a default error from chrome instead of an ASP.NET error page, for starters. Something might be going wrong in the overall page lifecycle. Are you able to breakpoint on PreRender?

Comment: @jcc - I have not.  This is the only way I have ever coded to handle it, I will  google for an example to achieve such.

Comment: I recommend reading this as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404969/asp-net-linkbutton-not-invoking-oncommand-event

Comment: @PeteM - the only event I have in pageload() is if (!IsPostBack) then populate the grid.

Comment: Have a look at this http://blog.vishalon.net/asp-net-datagrid-itemcommand-event-is-not-fired

Comment: @zdimension - not the instance, as I handcoded this from the start not a copy/paste

Comment: Can you hit any breakpoint at all? You shouldn't be getting generic chrome errors.

Comment: @PeteM - yes I hit other breakpoints that I add, however just this one is not hit.

Comment: Wait... are you not recreating the grid on postback? I'm admittedly a bit rusty with ASP.NET but I seem to recall you have to populate the grid with each postback or any controls hanging off of it won't technically exist. Can you provide your pageload method?

Comment: Have you tried turning the Exceptions on under the debug menu in VS? That should, stop somewhere near where your issue lies. You may need to crawl the call stack a bit though.

Comment: @DuncanHowe - how do I turn on exceptions/>?

Comment: Could you set things like text in the codebehind instead of render blocks? Sometimes missing a quote/single quote breaks things. Also you can try hard coding something to see if one of those render blocks is the problem.

Comment: Also - in IE there's a setting for "Friendly HTTP Errors" that hides the actual error for non-technical users. If Chrome has the same feature, shut it off so you can see the real error.

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy - under the debug menu in Visual Studio there is an "Exceptions" menu option. In the tree view is an entry for Common Language Runtime exceptions - next to that tick the "Thrown" column. If you don't have the menu option, you can add it to a toolbar by right clicking in the toolbar area and selecting `Customize...`. Depending upon your version of VS this is where it may differ, but take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for some MS guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I generally encounter this type of error if my aspx is malformed (forgot closing tag, etc.). Verify that you have the proper closing tags for your grid.

Also, can you show your Page_Load event codes as well as how you populate your grid?

Lastly, in your global.asax.cs, add the following lines of code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();
        if(exception != null)
        {
          // Do Some Stuff!
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

And put a breakpoint in the Server.ClearError(); line. This should allow you to see further what error is being raised.

Comment: See most recent edit.  grid is properly formated and I included syntax you needed to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Your error was posted on the global.asax output - Maximum request length exceeded. Something to do with your DB call.

Comment: The db call executes normal, and the grid loads.  But it's like once the grid loads the page will not allow any further filtering/link buttons to be pressed.

Comment: So what error is being posted in your global.asax now that the Maximum Request length exceeded is gone?